# Comment box not showing up?

Tags: support, comment

It seems when I click "Add comment" the box does not show up and neither can I see further comments when I click to expand.

Also I cannot access my privileges toggling the down arrow or my username.

Comment: It works on my ipad though.

Comment: Try to clear you cache, and check if Javascript works at all (e.g. by voting). This sounds like Javascript doesn't work for you for some reason.

Comment: @Fabian Thanks, clearing cache works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As answered in comments, the general thing to always try first is clearing your browser cache.

Sounds like that worked in this case.